# Why do complex eigenvalues correspond to a rotation of the vector?

Tags: linear-algebra

We have a linear transformation $T: \Bbb R^m \to \Bbb R^n$ defined by $T(x)=Ax$ for $x \in \Bbb R^m$ and $A \in M_{n \times m}(\Bbb R)$.  I understand why real-valued eigenvalues of $A$ correspond to scaling the length of the associated eigenvectors, but why is it that complex eigenvalues are said to rotate the eigenvector?

If you have an eigenvector $x = (x_1, x_2, x_3)$ whose eigenvalue is $\lambda = a+bi$, how is $\lambda x = ((a+bi)x_1, (a+bi)x_2, (a+bi)x_3)$ a rotation of $x$?  Shouldn't a rotation just be something like $\sin$'s and $\cos$'s multiplied by each component?  Where do the imaginary parts fit in?

Thanks.

Comment: Here is a link to what I found to be a great explanation of this  http://www.mathpages.com/home/kmath593/kmath593.htm

Comment: Do you know why multiplying two complex numbers together can be interpreted as a rotation?

Comment: @ChristopherA.Wong  It can be immediately seen from the polar form of complex numbers.  How does that help?

Comment: @Quality: Doesn't this just follow because complex multiplication is equivalent to scaling and rotating?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

First of all, eigenvalues and eigenvectors exist only for endomorphisms of a vector space, so you need $T:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}^n$ (same dimension).

Now, $T$ is given by multiplication with a matrix $A$ with real entries; you can extend $T$ to a map $T':\mathbb{C}^n\to\mathbb{C}^n$ given by the same matrix: $T'(z)=Az$. The real vector space you started from can be found as
$$V=\{\mathrm{Im}\; z_1=\ldots=\mathrm{Im}\; z_n=0\}$$
and it is fixed by $T'$, as $A$ has real coefficients.

Suppose $T$ has a complex eigenvalue $\lambda=a+ib$. It follows that $T'$ has the same eigenvalue; moreover, as $A$ has real coefficients, also $\bar\lambda=a-ib$ is an eigenvalue for $T$ and $T'$. Let $w\in\mathbb{C}^n$ be a (complex) eigenvector for $\lambda$, i.e.
$$T'(w)=Aw=\lambda w$$
then
$$T'(\bar{w})=A\bar{w}=\overline{Aw}=\overline{\lambda w}=\bar\lambda\bar{w}$$
i.e. $\bar{w}$ is an eigenvector for $\bar{\lambda}$.
Consider $W=\mathrm{Span}\{w,\bar{w}\}\subseteq\mathbb{C}^n$; this is an eigenspace for $T'$, so $W\cap V$ is fixed by $T$.

It is easy to believe that $W\cap V$ is made by the linear combinations of $w$ and $w'$ (with complex coefficients) which end up being real vectors.
Moreover, $\dim(W\cap V)=2$ as a real vector space: $W$ is $4$-dimensional over the reals, $V\cap W\neq W$ because $w, \bar{w}\not\in V$ (and they are linearly independent over the reals) and $V\cap W$ contains at least $w+\bar{w}$ and $i(w-\bar{w})$ which are linearly independent (over the real or complex numbers).

Hence $U=W\cap V$ is generated by $v_1=w+\bar{w}$ and $v_2=i(w-\bar{w})$ which, even if one of them contains an $i$, are with real coefficients.

Compute
$$T(v_1)=T'(w+\bar{w})=T'(w)+T'(\bar{w})=\lambda w+\overline{\lambda w}$$
$$T(v_2)=i(\lambda w-\overline{\lambda w})$$

If you write $\lambda=\rho(\cos\theta+i\sin\theta)$, then
$$\lambda w+\overline{\lambda w}=\rho(\cos\theta w + i \sin\theta w +\cos\theta\bar{w}-i\sin\theta\bar{w})=\rho\cos\theta (w+\bar{w}) + i\rho\sin\theta(w-\bar{w})$$
$$=\rho \cos\theta v_1 + \rho\sin\theta v_2$$
Similarly you can compute
$$T(v_2)=-\rho\sin\theta v_1+\rho\cos\theta v_2$$

So, $T$ restricted to $U$, with respect to the basis $\{v_1, v_2\}$, is given by the matrix
$$\rho\begin{pmatrix}\cos\theta&-\sin\theta\\\sin\theta&\cos\theta\end{pmatrix}$$
which is obtained composing an homotecy of ratio $\rho$ with a rotation of angle $\theta$.

---

By the way, the matix
$$A=\begin{pmatrix}1&1\\0&1\end{pmatrix}$$
does not act as a composition of dilations and rotations. The matrices which behave like that are only the ones of the form
$$\begin{pmatrix}a & -b\\b& a\end{pmatrix}$$
which constitute a subring of the $2\times 2$ matrices which is isomorphic to complex numbers and so, indeed, a field.

Comment: I find this answer very hard to follow

Answer (score 12):

Suppose for a moment that we have just the real vector space $V = \mathbb{R}^2$. Here is an example to see why a geometric rotation will correspond to a complex eigenvalue.

First, for a concrete example, say $M$ is a rotation by $90$ degrees. If we only consider real numbers, we can easily check that $M$ has no real eigenvalues. But suppose we want to "pretend" $M$ had some eigenvalue, $\lambda$. We don't know yet that $\lambda$ is complex, just that it can't be real.

We know there is some (nonzero) vector $x$ with $Mx = \lambda x$. Then $M^2x = \lambda^2 x$. But $M^2$ is a rotation by $180$ degrees, so $M^2 x = -x$. Hence $\lambda^2 = -1$. So $\lambda$ is a square root of $-1$ -- this immediately suggests we should look at complex numbers for $\lambda$, and in particular $\lambda$ should be be $i$ or $-i$.

Similarly, say $N$ is a rotation by $60$ degrees, which also has no real eigenvalues. Then we will have $N^3 = -I$, and so any eigenvalue of $N$ should be a non-real cube root of $-1$.

This is why rotations correspond with complex eigenvalues, in general: because iterated rotations go "around a circle" in the same way as iterated powers of complex numbers on the unit circle.

Answer (score 4):

There is one interpretation: let $a+bi$ be complex eigenvalue corresponding to eigenvector $v=v_1+iv_2$, where $v_1,v_2$ are real vectors. It can be proven that $a-bi$ is also eigenvalue correcponding to other vector $w=\overline{v}=v_1-iv_2$, so by definition:

$$Tv=(a+bi)v$$

$$Tw=(a-bi)w$$

In other form:

$$Tv_1+iTv_2=(a+bi)(v_1+iv_2)=av_1-bv_2+i(av_2+bv_1)$$

$$Tv_1-iTv_2=(a-bi)(v_1-iv_2)=av_1-bv_2-i(av_2+bv_1)$$

If you add these equations side by side you get:

$$Tv_1=av_1-bv_2$$

If you first multiply second by $-1$ you get:

$$Tv_2=bv_1+av_2$$

You can see analogy to rotation matrix:

$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}\begin{bmatrix}a && -b \\ b && a\end{bmatrix}$$

Answer (score 2):

For a real matrix, if $a + bi$ is an eigenvalue, so is $a - bi$. And in fact, the classic matrix with this pair of eigenvalues is 
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
a & -b \\
b & a
\end{bmatrix}.
$$

You probably know some theorems that say you can sometimes diagonalize a matrix by changing basis. In the cases where diagonalization isn't possible (for real matrices), which you *can* get is $2 \times 2$ blocks like that one on the diagonal.

So what's that $2 \times 2$ matrix do? Well, it multiplies lengths by $r = \sqrt{a^2 + b^2}$. So let's assume we've already factored that out into a diagonal matrix:
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
a & -b \\
b & a
\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}
r & 0 \\
0 &r
\end{bmatrix} \cdot 
\begin{bmatrix}
a' & -b' \\
b' & a'
\end{bmatrix}
$$
so that $a'^2 + b'^2 = 1$. Letting $\theta = \arctan(b'/a')$, we get $\sin \theta = b', \cos \theta = a'$, so this remaining matrix is just a rotation by angle $\theta$.

Does that help?

Comment: So complex eigenvalues scale AND rotate the vector?  Then what's so special about complex eigenvalues?  Can't we ALWAYS find a combination of a scaling and rotation that could reproduce what a matrix does to some arbitrary vector (I mean, other than scaling and rotating, what could a matrix even DO to a vector)?

Comment: @gotit--thanks Shear effects are neither. $\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix}$, for example, does more than just scale and rotate. In fact it does more than just changing coordinates, scaling and rotating, and changing coordinates back. (Matrices in this latter category are called diagonalizable.)

Comment: As Ian points out, there are matrices that aren't diagonalizable even over the complexes. But the point about non-real eigenvalues is that they represent rotations (perhaps along with some scaling), while real ones represent only scaling.

Comment: @gotit--thanks: I think this is precisely what SVD is about.

Answer (score 2):

Basically because Complex multiplication is equivalent to scaling and rotation. I think writing Complex numbers in polar form is the easiest way of seeing this.

Assume $$ Av = \lambda v ; \lambda \in \mathbb C$$

Now, we can write both $$ v, \lambda $$ in polar form , as , respectively

$$re^{i \theta}, r'e^{ i\theta'} $$

Then $$\lambda v = rr'e^{i(\theta + \theta' )} $$

So when multiplying $$v:=re^{i\theta} $$ we end up with

$$rr'e^{i ( \theta + \theta')} $$ which is $$v$$ stretched by a factor$$r'$$

And rotated by an angle $$ \theta' $$