# Which common linear transformations have imaginary/complex eigenvalues?

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors, linear-transformations

I've been curious which common classes of linear transformations correspond to real vs imaginary eigenvalues. For example, matrices which cause rotation in a linear transformation have imaginary eigenvalues.

Edit: Let's distinguish real from complex (as opposed to purely imaginary; references Ben Grossmann's comment)

Which others is this true for, specifically from the [Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transformation_matrix) list?

- Stretching
- Squeezing
- Shearing
- Reflection
- Orthogonal Projection

The following Q/A were a bit to proofy for me to follow. So the scope of this question is prioritizes "what" over "why." (Though, I'd happily accept both.)

[Why do complex eigenvalues correspond to a rotation of the vector?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1086037/why-do-complex-eigenvalues-correspond-to-a-rotation-of-the-vector)

[Imaginary eigenvalues](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1849712/imaginary-eigenvalues)

Comment: By "imaginary" do you mean "purely imaginary" or "complex"? For example, it's clear that $3i$ is an imaginary number, but do you consider $2 + 3i$ to be imaginary?

Comment: @BenGrossmann, great question! Let's distinguish real vs complex, as opposed to purely imaginary

Comment: None of those five have imaginary eigenvalues. The action of a pair of pure imaginary eigenvalues for a real matrix in real space is rotation in a 2D plane, that's all.

Comment: @Ian, Thanks! Though, I'm curious why rotation in 2D has imaginary EV but reflection does not. Any hints there?

Comment: A pure reflection would be something like $\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & -1 \end{bmatrix}$. It sends vectors in the "mirror" to themselves and vectors perpendicular to the "mirror" to their negative.

Comment: @jbuddy_13 Although I think it's perfectly clear what you mean, my inner pedant (as well as my outer pedant) wants to remind you that real numbers are actually complex numbers too. So, you want to distinguish between real numbers and non-real complex numbers. :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To go through the list:

- Every stretching/squeezing transformation has real, non-negative eigenvalues
- Every shear transformation has $1$ as its only eigenvalue
- Every reflection has eigenvalues $1$ or $-1$ (typically both)
- Every orthogonal projection has eigenvalues $0$ or $1$ (typically both)

As you noted, rotation matrices will have non-real eigenvalues, except in the case that the rotation angle(s) is a multiple of $180^\circ$. In other words, the eigenvalues will be non-real except in the case that the transformation can be thought of as a combination of "mutually orthogonal" reflections. Similarly, orthogonal transformations (transformations that can be done by a combination of reflections and rotations) will have non-real eigenvalues except in the case that all eigenvalues can be accounted for by a set of independent reflections.

Notably, reflections, orthogonal projections, and rotations (along with the orthogonal transformations) all fall into the class of "normal" transformation. A transformation is called normal if its matrix $A$ satisfies $A^TA = AA^T$ (where $A^T$ denotes the transpose of $A$). It turns out that a normal transformation will have real eigenvalues if and only if it is symmetric (that is, $A = A^T$).

Symmetric transformations all correspond to simultaneous streches/squeezes/reflections along mutually orthogonal axes. Normal transformations generalize this in that they also allow these transformations to include rotations about these same orthogonal axes (or more generally, within the planes containing any pair of axes).

Comment: Thanks for including the details on normal transformations; I wouldn't have thought to ask- but very insightful!

Comment: Quick follow up, is an orthogonal projection, at least in 2D, just a 90 degree rotation?

Comment: @jbuddy_13 It is not. You could think of it as doing nothing along certain axes and then "squishing to zero" along others.